# Sharing ReactJS components in different projects without publishing in NPM

Tags: reactjs, npm, components

I am creating a library of components to use it in differents projecs. I cannot publish it in npm so I am linking them throw (npm i '../../local-lib-path'). When I build the main app (that uses the library) it gave me the following error, corresponding to the library component:

```
NodeInvocationException: Prerendering failed because of error: Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (53:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| 
| return (
> <Button icon="download" onClick={getReport} {...props} > Export </Button>
|
```

As I can understand, the Webpack does not compile the components from the library. I have to pass the library compiled? How can I compile a library (I do not want an app, just export components)

Thank you very much for your time!

In my library, I import the component like this. where the button is created as a normal react component in `../components/App`

```
import ExportButton from '../components/App'

export { ExportButton }
```

In the main app, in my json I have:

```
"export-buton": "file:../../components/components",
```

and I used it as

```
import {ExportButton} from 'export-button'
```

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question but have you tried https://bit.dev ?

Comment: you can use yarn workspaces. It handles all the symlinks for your packages